# How to debug/step-into npm package with Typescript source code?

Tags: angular, angular6

[Okta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-angular) (Angular NPM dependency) is not behaving/returning the values that I'm expecting. I would like to step into its source code as I'm debugging my application so I can understand what's happening and fix the issue. How do I do this in my Angular 6 app?

I'm using `ng serve --source-map --vendor-source-map` ([as shown here](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/07/27/angular-cli-6.1/)) to bootup Angular but that doesn't work. When I try to debug into a method called `isAuthenticated()` defined in `OktaAuthService` class, Chrome's debugger shows this error:

`Could not load content for webpack:///../../../../src/okta/services/okta.service.ts : HTTP status code: 404`

I couldn't find this file in Okta's npm package but I did find its type definition file, `okta.service.d.ts`. Does this mean Okta's NPN package doesn't include the TS source code along with its transpiled JS code? Is there an npm/Angular option that will allow me to download the Okta package along with its source code for debugging purposes?

**What versions am I using?**

When I run `ng --version`, I get the following:

```
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.5
@schematics/update                0.7.5
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

This is what's in my `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/common": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/http": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^6.1.6",
        "@angular/router": "^6.1.6",
        "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
        "@okta/okta-angular": "^1.3.0",
        "@primer/octicons": "^9.1.1",
        "@types/dom-inputevent": "^1.0.4",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
        "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "class-validator": "^0.9.1",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.10",
        "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
        "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^7.1.0",
        "ngx-quill": "^7.2.0",
        "popper": "^1.0.1",
        "quill": "^1.3.6",
        "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
        "stackedit-js": "^1.0.7",
        "typescript-string-operations": "^1.3.1",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
    }
```

Comment: Generally, the npm dist packages are what your application is running which are minified and not human readable.  The source may not be in ts at all. Stepping through may not be a viable option.  The problem here probably isn't in okta, and you can just log things or step through your own code to figure out what's going wrong. Or if a package is causing this much headache, it might not be worth it.

Comment: Which angular cli version are you using ?

Answer (score 3):

i can probably help you out here with a little playing around.  I've been in the same situation and got it working before, but i'm not sure if I can remember how.

is it possible you have Okta's .map files, if you MANUALLY include those, it should help with the .js -> .ts debugging??

Also I did find the file in question.  It might be as easy as downloading the source files and putting them in the expected src folder (from the error message?)

https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/okta-angular/src/okta/services

It is very possible that they won't include the .ts source code files in their "build" or "bundle" that they distribute, but it does appear that you can pull them from github, so maybe that's the trick you need?

Let me know if you have any luck there?

you could also edit the .js files and add a debugger; statement

Comment: Unfortunately copying the source code into `okta-angular` didn't work. I got the following error: `ERROR in ./node_modules/@okta/okta-angular/dist/src/okta/components/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: H:\@MyApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@okta\okta-angular\dist\src\okta\components\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library.`

Comment: `Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format 
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (H:\@MyApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:749:23)       
    at plugin.done.then (H:\@MyApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:41:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Comment: Anyways, I figured out the source of my problem without the ability to debug the library with TS source code. So it's no longer important that I have this ability. I'll give you the bounty for your efforts.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development'
};
```

in angular.json

```
{
  "architect": {
    "build": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
         HERE
```

Or just use the good old `console.log`.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't even know where I would set `mode: 'development'`. Nor do I know what values should be in `customWebpackConfig`

Comment: I think it would be easier for you to put `console.log()` in the places you need the output. Just edit the JS-files inside `node_modules`.